# matplotlib subplots only showing one subplot at a time

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

The following code

```
    batch_size = 4
    plt.figure()
    for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(loader):
        plt.title(f"i_batch = {i_batch}")
        for i_sample in range(sample_batched.shape[0]):
            ax = plt.subplot(int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), i_sample + 1)
            ax.set_title(f"Sample #{i_sample}")
            ax.axis("off")
            plt.imshow(sample_batched[i_sample, :, :])
            plt.pause(0.001)
    plt.show()
```

which I copied-augmented from [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) gives me outputs such as

[image]

and

[image]

[The image data is fine]

How do I get all 4 samples to show at the same time as subplots?

What did I do wrong?

---

EDIT:

Here is working code.

```
for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(loader):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), int(np.sqrt(batch_size)))
    fig.suptitle(f"i_batch = {i_batch}")
    for i_sample, ax in zip(range(sample_batched.shape[0]), axs.flat):
        # ax = plt.subplot(int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), i_sample + 1)
        ax.set_title(f"Sample #{i_sample}")
        ax.axis("off")
        ax.imshow(sample_batched[i_sample, :, :])
        plt.pause(0.001)
```

[image]

This is annoying because I don't understand what the original code was trying to do, without using `subplots`, and without the strange separation between a `figure` and a `subplot` named `ax`

I would like some better top-down explanation on this, not just a working example for this one time.

The docs are not explaining the logic.

Comment: isn't it just overlapping your previous image?

Comment: @KevinChoi Maybe it does. How do I get it right? I can't seem to understand how `subplot` works

Comment: maybe you should use fig.add_subplot instead of .subplot

Comment: @KevinChoi Sorry, `Maybe` doesn't work for me. I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you want to check your code, I recommend you to plot the image at the end of each loop. This is what I usually do if I messed up with my python for loop system

Comment: @KevinChoi I don't need debugging help, thanks. I need an explanation about how `plt.subplot` actually works